# Setting up connect-flash middleware for use by passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I want to access the message that my passport strategy specifies in its callback, like this: `done(null, false, { message: 'No such user.' });`. I found out so far that these messages can be displayed by passing the option `failureFlash: true` into the `passport.authenticate()` function, the usage of which again requires `connect-flash` middleware to be installed. So I installed the module and added `var flash = require('connect-flash);` to my source, as well as `app.use(flash());` to the configuration method of my express app. But it still crashes with the error that a method `.flash()` is not available. What did I miss?

More code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var googleStrategy = require('passport-google').Strategy;
var flash = require('connect-flash');

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new googleStrategy(
    { 
        returnURL: 'http://localhost:123456/auth/google/return', 
        realm: 'http://localhost:123456/' 
    },
    function(identifier, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
            User.findOne({ ID: identifier }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }

                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'no such user' });
                }

                return done(null, user);
            });
        });
    })
);

var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'veryverysecretsecret' }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(flash());
});

app.get(
    '/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
    function (req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);

app.get('/auth/google/return',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
    function (req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);

http.createServer(app).listen(123456);
```

Comment: where are you using `.flash()`?

Comment: I am not. Not explicitly, that is. As far as my understanding goes, it will be called by passport when redirecting to the failure route.

Comment: hmmm... can you post more source?

Comment: Hmm, I guess I could. Let me just pick out the relevant pieces.

Comment: two suggestions, try moving the app.use(flash()) declaration before the passport declaration, and also make sure you have flash in your dependencies in package.json and installed. (I know it probably is, but it never hurts to check).

Comment: @JasonNichols moving the app.use(flash()) up actually worked, thanks! Add it as an answer, will you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Passport needs flash to be configured before itself.

To fix your problem, just change the order in `app.configure()`, and move the passport use below it, like so:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'veryverysecretsecret' }));
    app.use(flash());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
});

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new googleStrategy(
    { 
        returnURL: 'http://localhost:123456/auth/google/return', 
        realm: 'http://localhost:123456/' 
    },
    function(identifier, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
            User.findOne({ ID: identifier }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }

                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'no such user' });
                }

                return done(null, user);
            });
        });
    })
);
```

Glad it helped!